# Windows UWP - Modify AppX Package At Runtime

Tags: c#, dll, uwp, appx, appxmanifest

We need to dynamically load assemblies at runtime in order to include customization for our users. However, after looking all over the web, I cannot find any information on whether Microsoft plan to make this feature possible or not. I have started a feature request here:
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/18145291-dynamically-load-assembly

Failing that, I figured that it may be possible to manually add assemblies in to the AppX package, and then force the user to quit, and reopen the app. Yes, this is horrible, but I don't see any way around this currently. Are there any examples out there on how to modify the AppX package?

Or, is this idea thwarted because the package would lose its certificate signing?

Comment: UWP apps (and WinRT and Silverlight) are part of the new app model Microsoft is pushing. point of it is that each app is isolated in its own sandbox and it will never have bad effects on the system. Microsoft says that you will never be sorry for downloading an app from the store which is why they need to make sure they are safe to use. loading assemblies at runtime or modifying the current app installation folder will open up exploitation possibilities and will break the app promise of Microsoft. so IMO I don't think they will ever do it.

Comment: Yep. Seems that way. I'm pretty sure that Microsoft will never have to worry about people regretting downloading apps from their store. The platform is so limited that nobody is going to bother writing apps for it anyway.

Comment: The death of windows phones and the barren app store for phones shows how much of a failure UWP is.